# Does overriding == for a object change the behavior of include? method of an array?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Example:

```
class CustomObject
  .....
  def ==(other)
    self.x == other.x && self.y =! other.y
  end
  .....
end

array_of_custom_objects = CustomObject.load_for(company_id: company_id)
new_custom_object = CustomObject.new(....)

array_of_custom_objects.include? new_custom_object
```

My question is does the array `include?` method compare two objects bases on the defination of `==` method?

Bascially, will the above code determine whether my **new_custom_object** is included in the array of **CustomObject** by evaluating the overridden **==** method for each insance of **CustomObject** in the array with **new_custom_object**?

Comment: Yes. "Returns `true` if for some index `i` in `self`, `obj == self[i]`; otherwise `false`"

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: @Ry- yes, the actual code is a bit different, but the issue is, the program execution never reaches the overridden == method at all. I was expecting when i run the array_of_custom_objects.include? new_custom_object code, the context would switch to the == for each object in array but that doesn't seem to happen

Comment: You should probably [edit] your question to be about that issue, then, along with other context. For example, is `array_of_custom_objects` actually an array, or is it some other collection type, maybe provided by an ORM?

Comment: `=!` is a red flag. Are you sure that's not meant to be `!=` or `==`? `=!` means "set the left hand side to the Boolean negation of the right hand side and return its value", which is not a normal thing to do in an equality comparison.

Comment: _"Does overriding == for a object change the behavior of include?"_ – you may get a different _result_ but the _behavior_ of `include?` won't change. It will still send `==` to each element, checking for a truthy return value. (this behavior is actually why overriding `==` works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is does the array include? method compare two objects bases on the defination of == method?

Yes. As said in: https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F

> include?(obj) → true or false click to toggle source
>
> Returns true if for some index i in self, obj == self[i]; otherwise false:

---

Seems to be working, (though I'm not sure if this is the most optimal way of doing things as we don't know the context of your code):

```rb
class CustomObject
  attr_reader :x, :y, :z

  def initialize(x, y, z)
    @x = x
    @y = y
    @z = z
  end

  def ==(other)
    self.x == other.x && self.y != other.y
  end
end

custom_objects = []
new_custom_object_1 = CustomObject.new(1, 2, 3)
custom_objects << new_custom_object_1

new_custom_object_2 = CustomObject.new(2, 3, 4)
custom_objects << new_custom_object_2

search_object = CustomObject.new(2, 7, 4) # 2 == 2 && 3 != 7

puts custom_objects.include?(search_object)
# => true

search_object = CustomObject.new(2, 3, 4) # 2 == 2 && 3 != 3

puts custom_objects.include?(search_object)
# => false
```